# How can I remove my ip from the blacklist ivmSIP / 24?

Tags: email, ip, blacklist

I checked my server IP with this tool:

http://www.mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx

It has appeared in the ivmSIP / 24 list.

What can I do to remove my IP from this list? I have SPF records set to allow this IP to send mail on behalf of the domain.

I already sent several mails to delist@invaluement.com, any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: "I already sent several mails to delist@invaluement.com, any ideas?" Wait a while for a response.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is more: Why are you on that list?

Asking to get you removed from the BlackList isn´t that useful, if the issues which caused the blacklisting isn´t solved. So for example "An virus is using your mailserver to spread SPAM" then there might be legal ways why you are blacklisted again and again.

So the first step would be to find the reason why you are blacklisted, then remove that. Normally it takes some time to remove you from that blacklist automatically. However based on your actions you performed to prevent that you will be blacklisted again you might inform the blacklist owner.

*P.S. adding a SPF record need some time to travel true DNS replication & cache environments*